# Checking if point inside polygon is not very exact - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a function that check if point is inside polygon in javascript, but this function is not very exact, because i have 5 polygons sticking to each other and when i click in polygon 1, the function tells me the polygon 2 was clicked, because they are very close.

So, this is my function:

```
 function isInsidePolygon(testx, testy, face, nvert){
    var coords = getFaceCoords(face);
    var vertx = [ coords[0][0], coords[1][0], coords[2][0], coords[3][0] ];
    var verty = [ coords[0][1], coords[1][1], coords[2][1], coords[3][1] ]; 

    var i, j, c = false;
    for( i = 0, j = nvert-1; i < nvert; j = i++ ) {
        if( ( ( verty[i] > testy ) != ( verty[j] > testy ) ) &&
            ( testx < ( vertx[j] - vertx[i] ) * ( testy - verty[i] ) / ( verty[j] - verty[i] ) + vertx[i] ) ) {
                c = !c;
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

To better the explain about problem i will post function "getFaceCoords()", look:

// Retorna as coordenadas da face

```
function getFaceCoords(face) {
    var coords = new Object();

    // todos os pontos do dente
    var x1y1 = [ 34, 27 ];
    var x2y2 = [ 94, 27 ];
    var x3y3 = [ 94, 89 ];
    var x4y4 = [ 34, 89 ];
    var x5y5 = [ 47, 41 ];
    var x6y6 = [ 82, 41 ];
    var x7y7 = [ 82, 75 ];
    var x8y8 = [ 46, 75 ];

    if (face == 'DISTAL') {
        coords = [ x1y1, x5y5, x8y8, x4y4 ];
    } else if (face == 'LINGUAL') {
        coords = [ x1y1, x2y2, x6y6, x5y5 ];
    } else if (face == 'MESIAL') {
        coords = [ x2y2, x3y3, x7y7, x6y6 ];
    } else if (face == 'VESTIBULAR') {
        coords = [ x3y3, x4y4, x8y8, x7y7 ];
    } else if (face == 'OCLUSAL') {
        coords = [ x5y5, x6y6, x7y7, x8y8 ];
    }

    // Configura os pontos conforme parametrizaÃ§Ã£o
    for ( var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
        coords[i][0] = coords[i][0] + startPoint;
        coords[i][1] = coords[i][1] + startPoint;
    }

    return coords;

}
```

The value of "startPoint" variable is "-25". IF you draw this polygons in a cartesian plane, you will see that is very close, stuck, really.

So the only problem is the precision that is bad. See my polygons, area 5 exactly: http://www.odontoblogia.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/face-dente.jpg

Comment: Can you provide example of input arguments for `isInsidePolygon`?

Comment: Looking at your code real quickly, doesn't look like you're using the [even/odd rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon), that might make your life a little easier.

Comment: the problem is: the polygon are so close, and i have to define a "epsilon" to get a ray outside of polygon until my point. If my epsilon is very large i can get another polygon that i shouldn't

Comment: Look this is my polygons, are 5 exactly. http://www.odontoblogia.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/face-dente.jpg